# Trigger event in API.ai from MS Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, botframework, dialogflow-es

I am using the [api-ai-recognizer](https://github.com/GanadiniAkshay/ApiAiRecognizer) module for nodejs to integrate API.ai's NLP with a bot that uses Microsoft Bot Framework. API.ai allows you to trigger intents via "user says" or events. I cannot find any documentation or examples on how to trigger/initialize API.ai events via MS Bot Framework. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using API.AI with "events" (=webhook) is exactly what `api-ai-recognizer` + `botbuilder` provides you.

Once a request is being sent to your `botbuilder`, `api-ai-recognizer` will pass the text content of your message to `api-ai` and will return the recognized intent + entities.

In that point `botbuilder` will route the conversation to an appropriate dialog.

I would suggest you to read the docs of `API.AI` for more info. and more specifically regarding the webhook here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#authentication

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I still am unsure of what you mean. How would you, for instance, trigger the default "Welcome" event, which triggers Default Welcome Intent in my case. Could you provide some pseudocode or an example? Thank you.

Comment: To trigger an event like welcome you'll need to customize the `api-ai-recognizer` package, as it does not have support for it currently. (or sending those events by your own)